# Get and Set data-attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I need to save a value "disk-size" for a td in a table and then set the same value to another td. I am trying to use data-attributes, but cannot figure out how to make this happen. Here is my code:

```
function addOnDrop(x)
{
    if(currentDisk < 12)
    {
        var td = document.getElementsByClassName("vArray-td");
        td[currentDisk].innerHTML = x.html();
        td[currentDisk].style.backgroundColor = "black";
        td[currentDisk].data("disk-size",x.data("disk-size"));
        array.push(parseInt(x.data("disk-size")));
    }
}
```

I am dealing with two tables where the value of the attribute "data-disk-size" should be copied from one td to the other. In the code, x is a jQuery UI.draggable object of the first table td and td[currentDisk] is the second table td. I want to set td[currentDisk]."data-disk-size" = x."data-disk-size". I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on this line:

```
td[currentDisk].data("disk-size",x.data("disk-size"));
```

How am I supposed to accomplish this? And I guess the broad question is how do I get and set custom attributes in JavaScript?

(This is my first post to Stack Overflow so I apologize if I did something wrong.)

Comment: You're trying to call a jQuery method on a native DOM element..

Comment: `data()` is a jQuery function. You're trying to apply it to a DOM element directly, not the jQuery wrapper. I suggest you not switch back and forth between raw Javascript and jQuery if it confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

`.data` is jQuery.

The [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) way is:

```
td[currentDisk].setAttribute("data-disk-size",x.getAttribute("data-disk-size"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you `data` is a jQuery method.  So the following line is invalid because `td[currentDisk]` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object:

```
td[currentDisk].data("disk-size",x.data("disk-size"));
```

It should look more like this:

```
$(td[currentDisk]).attr("data-disk-size",$(x).attr("data-disk-size"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, I suggest you use it consistently:

```
var td = $(".vArray-td").eq(currentDisk);
td.html(x.html()).css("background-color", "black")
                 .data("disk-size", x.data("disk-size");
array.push(x.data("disk-size"));
```